# Binding List of objects to ListView not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, view, viewmodel

There is a problem with my `ListView` binding, it is not showing anything in the list.
I have the following ViewModel:

```
namespace Users.ViewModel
{
    public class AllUsersViewModel
    {
        public List<Module> _modules = new List<Module>();

        #region Constructor

        public AllUsersViewModel()
        {
            this.SetModuleList();
        }

        void SetModuleList()
        {
            _modules = ModuleRepository.GetModules();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `GetModules()` function is return the set just fine. I have done a check by loop through the _modules List.
Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstModules" Width="190" ItemsSource="{Binding _modules}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What is the problem, why doesn't the `ListBox` populate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_modules` is a field, and you cannot bind to fields. Make a property which exposes the value of `_modules`:

```
public IEnumerable<Module> Modules
{
    get { return _modules; }
}
```

and bind to this property instead:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstModules" Width="190" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
```

Comment: Tried it, copied and pasted your examples without changing anything else, the ListBox is still displaying empty

Comment: Then you should check `DataContext` value of `lstModules`.

Answer (score 0):

The Modules collection should be a property, not a variable.

```
public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
```